# How to read and parse json file from html tag

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have some html file with a script tag of type `application/json', i am trying to read that json on my javascript code which is on separate file and loaded to that html. But i can only find jQuery examples, and i want to do it in pure javascript.

Here is an example on jquery:

```
<script id="myJson" type="application/json">
 { 
   name: 'Foo' 
 }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var x = JSON.parse($('#myJson').html());
        alert(x.name); //Foo
     });
</script>
```

my code:

```
<script src="Game.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" id="data">
{'name':'foo'}
</script>
```

Javascript code:

```
var json_file = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data'));
```

Comment: Why down votes? please explain so i know what i did wrong.

Comment: the json you have written is just javascript, why not just use a normal script tag and expose a variable on the window

Comment: What is purpose of using `<script>` element? Could you create a `.json` file which contains `{ 
   "name": "Foo"
 }`?

Comment: The json is all the questions and answers for a game i am building(or trying to build). i don't want to store it in the javascript file, cause it can be loaded from different html pages using different json data. i want the javascript to read it form the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't find the json as the json isn't there when the js script runs, put the json tag before the javascript script tag. Also, what you have there as json isn't (valid) json. json has `"`, not `'`.

So

```
<script type="application/json" id="data">
    {"name":"foo"}
</script>
<script src="Game.js"></script>
```

Would work, provided you have something like

```
JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML)
```

in `Game.js`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed `JSON` in an `html` element, you can use `Element.dataset`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById("myJson").dataset.json))
}
```

```html
<script id="myJson" type="text/plain" data-json='{"name":"Foo"}'></script>
```